# How to Pan and Zoom on a Form

Tags: c#, bitmap, bmp

So, I have been using this code to display an image for an application I am working on.

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(global::Map.Properties.Resources.bigmap, 0, 0, 980, 980);
```

Which in turn gives me this. (Edit: New guys can't post images. Sorry. You can however view it here- [Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD5Su.jpg))

Which is nice and all but considering the resolution is around 3500X3500 I would like to be able to zoom and pan it. So, is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem this very week.

Try something [like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12331/ImageBox-Control-with-Zoom-Pan-Capability).
It worked well for me.

Comment: Can you explain to me how I convert from what I have to an image box? I apologize my experience with C# is limited.

Comment: Looks like you are including your image as a Resource.  So to implement smallwisdom's code in your situation, look at the Form1.cs file, lines 130 and 131.  In there he is taking the image from an "Open File Dialog".  Instead of that, you will use your Resource Image.  Something like this : 
'zoomPanImageBox1.Image = ZoomPanExample.Properties.Resources.bigmap;'

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty method? Save the image to an external file and open it in a WebBrowser control. Provides built-in panning and zooming. Otherwise, you'll need to capture mouse movements, scroll wheel handlers, etc... All of which can be done, but is much more work. To save the image, from what I can tell from your code, just:

```
Map.Properties.Resources.bigmap.Save(System.Environment.CurrentLocation + "\\temp.bmp");
MapWebBrowser.Navigate(System.Environment.CurrentLocation + "\\temp.bmp");
```

Apologies if the code doesn't work out of the box, but it should be a good starting point. I don't have a copy of C# with me right now. Let me know if you need more explanation. (MapWebBrowser needs to be added, its just a WebBrowserControl).